# how to disable capture when upload image file (using safari on ipad)

Tags: html, ipad, upload, safari

I would like to upload a image using safari on ipad
here is my html code

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*">
```

When i try to select a file, safari prompt me to choose "take photo" or "select existed file", how can i disable the "take photo" options, and just select an existing file?

I also look up w3c document, and try codes below, but not work

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="filesystem">
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to this [HTML5 compatibility comparator](http://mobilehtml5.org/), Safari supports only partially the media capture feature: it complies with the `accept` attribute but ignores the `catpure` attribute.

So I am afraid you will have to wait for a better support from Safari before it works the way you want...

What's more, according to [the W3C specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-media-capture-20120712/#the-capture-attribute):

> When the capture attribute is specified, the user agent ***SHOULD*** invoke a file picker of the specific capture control type.

[The keyword SHOULD](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) means that Safari can choose not to follow the recommendation for some reason and still claim to be compliant with the standard...