# Safari crash while taking photo in iPhone 4S [iOS 8.1]

Tags: ios, iphone, safari

I am using following code for capture photo and display/store. This same code working fine in iPhone 5 with iOS 7.1.2 but in iPhone 4S with iOS 8.1 safari will crash every time when i take photo.

```
<body>
    <img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
    <input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PreviewImage() {
            var oFReader = new FileReader();
            oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
            oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
                document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
            };
        };
    </script>
</body>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nsemaz2y/)
Following message show in safari after take photo

> A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded

**Update**
Now i am doing same task on same device but with iOS version 8.1.2. Still same problem occured

Comment: Is it **Crash** or **Crush**

Comment: I am having the same issue on my iPhone 4, and my boss was having the same issue on iPhone 5, but after he updated his to iOS 8.1.1 his problem was resolved; mine however presists even with iOS 8.1.1

Comment: Having the same issue. Oddly enough it doesnt happen with video.

Comment: Yeah. I think they will not handle that for iphone 4s.  Well hope for best. Lets see what will happen in next ios release.

Comment: I was having the same problem with iOS 8.1.1 on an iPhone 6 Plus but it seems that iOS 8.1.2 has solved it

Comment: it happens on my iPhone 6 with iOS 8.1.1 as well.

Comment: anyone test with IPhone 4s with 8.1.2?. i think it resolve in iphone 6 with 8.1.2. but not sure about 4s

Comment: It still happens after Update 8.1.2 on iPhone 4s :(

Comment: Having same issue, any fix for this?

Comment: Not in my knowledge yet.

Comment: Could it be lack of memory? Has anyone looking into the stack trace? If you select a photograph instead of taking a picture it appears to work...

Comment: yeah in my case it is only crash while taking photo (as mention in question). Not while selecting from library. But i cannot able to fix that on my end yet.

Comment: Also experiencing this behavior in a 6 Plus running the latest (8.1.3). If you select an existing photo, no problem. If, however, you take a photo "live", crash occurs.

Comment: I checked this with `IPhone 5` with latest iOS (8.1.3) it worked fine in both cases i.e taking photo and selecting from library. But still not working in IPhone 4S with 8.1.3

Comment: It works for me on iOS 8.3 beta, safari doesn't crash. (iPhone 6)

Comment: Could it be a stack overflow due to lack of memory in the buffer (transferring from camera)? This would explain why you can upload a picture, but taking a photo causes it to crash.

Comment: Please change the event form onchange to onblur (<input id="uploadImage" type="file" name="myPhoto" onblur="PreviewImage();">

Comment: Anyone please check @AltimirAntonov suggestion. Check on IPhone 4S with ios 8 or on 6 plus.. On IPhone 5 with ios 8.1.3 it works fine with 'onChange' Event.

Comment: What happened why mu code?

Comment: @AltimirAntonov. nothing happened. I just want that someone check your code in IPhone 4S. because i don't have 4s now.

Comment: @BilalBlu  Changing the event form onchange to onblur didnt make any effect. did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @kumar i didn't find yet

Answer (score 1):

Although the 8.1 update fixed it on newer devices, on older devices (first iPad, iPad Mini, iPhone 4S) the problem still existed. iOS 8.2 didn't do a better job. However, with the release of 8.3 yesterday, the problem was resolved. Prior to the 8.3 update I checked with iOS 8.2 and with every picture safari crashed. Sometimes during the camera mode, sometimes after the picture was taken. Hopefully the problem is now resolved for others as well.

For the other devices a factory restore did resolve the problem, but also removed any app, settings and data. Not really the way to go.

The code I used for testing can be found in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d6nwubx3/6/

```
var inputComponent = document.getElementById('fileuploader');
inputComponent.addEventListener('change',handleFileSelect, false);
function handleFileSelect( event ) { 
    var image = event.target.files[0];
    // Do something with image
}
```

Comment: I tried our your demo on my iPhone 6+ w/ 8.3, and still getting the same error when taking a photo, but working using the photo library. It has no issues with using the google chrome app, but safari is failing everytime.

Comment: I  found out that the problem still exists on some devices. Andy, could you provide a crash log (https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/ios/crash/)? Currently I have no device near and Apple wants a crash log. Would be really great.

Comment: I'm experiencing the crash (and subsequent reload of the page) on iOS 8.4 on an iPhone 6 Plus. I modified your jsfiddle to reproduce when it crashes for me (when I try to put the local image into an <img>): http://jsbin.com/gowiwe/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: @jonsibley - I'm also suffering from this problem - did you find a solution?

Comment: @AlexFox No, I haven't found a solution. I'm pretty confident that it's a memory issue, because after closing tabs or force-restarting Safari, using the camera to attach a photo via <input> no longer crashes the Safari tab. Please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: if this is still an issue, can someone upload or email a crashlog? That way Apple might have a look at it and it can get fixed. Too bad this seems to occur, although none of my devices has this problem at the moment.

Comment: @jonsibley - this happens to me in UKWebView on iOS 8.4 using an iPhone 6+. I've tested with an iPhone 5 and it's fine. I don't get a crash report in XCode or in the WebKit console which is pretty annoying. I just get a blank white screen, though the app still seems to be running in XCode

Comment: @gjadmiraal I submitted a Bug Report to Apple with a sample project to reproduce the issue. A mirror of the report can be found here: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5006458726907904

Comment: @jonsibley any update on bug report? Is there any workaround for this as I can see the issue in iPhone 6 consistently.

Comment: @kumar unfortunately, no update on the bug report yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug which appears to be happening in iOS 8.1.2 and 8.1.3. I was able to reproduce the issue in multiple scenarios and I am in the process of filing a bug with Apple.

**Possible Workaround:**
Allow the user to select multiple files by setting

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple>
```

This disables the "Take Photo" option, but you must support multiple file uploads.

On other browsers, setting the `capture` attribute allows finer control of whether or not the user is allowed to take photos as part of the file selection, but according to [how to disable capture when upload image file (using safari on ipad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23234596/how-to-disable-capture-when-upload-image-file-using-safari-on-ipad) *it is not respected by mobile safari*.